# Power BI gateway connection dataset getting refreshed but report couldn't access the data source

Tags: powerbi, gateway

We have install Power BI gateway and connect SSAS live connection. Create the PBI report and publish it. On Power BI service, we are getting error "PBI report couldn't access the data source" but if we check dataset, its getting refreshed every hour means gateway connection is perfect. We have properly map user but still not working. What to do changes in gateway connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Report-couldn-t-access-the-data-source/td-p/761986

As mentioned above, it solved by deleting the database role and re-creating it.